# Changing team name that appears in stats in CS:GO

Tags: steam, counter-strike-global-offensive

The in-game stats window in Counter-Strike: Global Offensive includes a highlighted prefix before certain players's names. It seems to be a team/clan tag like players sometimes include directly in their Steam display names.

[image]

I went through the in-game settings but I don't see any place to specify this. There's no option to type in a type in a team name, or any way to join a team.

How do I change the my team name?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The team names are representative of the groups that you belong to on Steam.

In order to change the team name you must belong to any group that has a tag. You can find these groups under the Community section of your Steam Interface. Many public groups are open to join with little hassle. Simply click the join group link on the right hand side.

After you sign up to any of these groups you can change your settings in game to the tag you want. In game go to "Settings menu" → "Game Settings" → "Team"  →  "Steam Group Clan Tag":

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Do you belong to more than one group in Steam? The groups don't have to be CS:GO specific to show the tag.

Comment: No Steam says I'm only in one group.

Comment: Get a few screenshots and ask it as a new question. One from in game showing the two clan tags and one from the groups you belong to.

Answer (score 1):

`mp_teamname_1` and `mp_teamname_2` in the console

optional: `mp_teamlogo_1` and `mp_teamlogo_2` i.e `mp_teamlogo_1 vp` (short for Virtus Pro)
`mp_teamlogo_2 liq` (short for Team Liquid) and `mp_teamflag 1` and `mp_teamflag_2`)

Comment: You should explain what this does. Code-only answers are not helpful without an explanation.

Comment: [Apparently these are settings that can be used on a private server to configure arbitrary team names, and flags/logos from a list, which will appear on the scoreboard. These are used for some professional tournaments.](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=516354540) Some of this information could be integrated into the answer, with a link to a source for more details.